# Can't resolve all parameters for Component Webpack4

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, angular6, webpack-4

I'm trying to build webpack dev environment, using angular 6 webpack 4
this is my error I get after I got compiled successfully 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLIxF.png)

**webpack.config.common**

```js
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app/main.ts',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: ['html-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['raw-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        loader: ['url-loader?limit=100000']
      }
    ],
    exprContextCritical: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

**webpack.config.dev**

```js
var path = require('path');

var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common');

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true
            }
          },
          { loader: 'angular2-template-loader' },
          { loader: 'angular-router-loader' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"]
  }
}
```

**MainComponnent**

```js
import { User } from '../models/user.model';
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  NgZone
} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../user.service';
import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common';
import { ConnectionService } from '../app/connection.service';
import { AlertMessageDialogComponent } from '../alertMessageDialog/alertmessagedialog.component';
import { MainService } from './main.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

  private userClaims: User;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.getUserDetailstoMain();
    this.userService.getUserClaims().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.userClaims = data;
      let NameArray = this.userClaims['User']['FullName'].split(' ', 2);
      this.globalItems.UserFirstName = NameArray[0];
      this.globalItems.UserLastName = NameArray[1];
      this.globalItems.UserPhoto = this.userClaims['User']['UserPhoto'];
    });
  }
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    private location: PlatformLocation,
    private router: Router,
    private connectionService: ConnectionService,
    private globalItems: MainService,
    private zone: NgZone
  ) {}
  logOut(event) {
    sessionStorage.clear();
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      location.reload();
    });
  }

}
```

```js
{
  "name": "cloud-crp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "index.js",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "build": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --port 8080 --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "build:prod": "del-cli dist && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'src/app/**/*.js' 'src/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'src/app/**/*.js.map' 'src/app/**/*.shim.ts' 'src/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'src/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts' 'dist/app' 'src/polyfills.ngsummary.json'",
    "clean": "del-cli dist && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && del-cli 'src/app/**/*.js' 'src/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'src/app/**/*.js.map' 'src/app/**/*.shim.ts' 'src/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'src/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts' 'dist/app' 'src/polyfills.ngsummary.json'",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^6.0.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^1.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^7.0.1",
    "angular": "^1.6.9",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular2-focus": "^1.1.2",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-mdl": "^2.13.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^6.0.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-kw-gauge": "^0.0.8",
    "ng2-password-strength-bar": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-select": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.3",
    "ngx-pipes": "^2.1.2",
    "ngx-popper": "^2.7.1",
    "object-fit-images": "^3.2.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
    "primeng": "^5.2.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.2.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "tether": "^1.4.4",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.10.2",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.0",
    "@types/node": "7.0.7",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.7.1",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-justgage": "^0.3.0",
    "angular2-recaptcha": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-loader": "^2.2.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "codelyzer": "~4.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "del-cli": "^0.2.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "tether": "^1.4.3",
    "ts-node": "^4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.9.1",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^4.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.2"
  }
}
```

### -----------------------------------

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

Comment: Can you try ngOnInit after constructor declaration?

Comment: @Pradnya Sinalkar thanks but didn't work,

Comment: maybe You are missing an ```@Injectable()``` annotation on on one of your   ```UserService```,```ConnectionService```,```MainService``` services.

Comment: @fatemefazli, I just checked and I'm not missing any @injectable() annotation.

Comment: @saahaalaa - post your `package.json`

Comment: @fernandoespinosa add to the post

Answer (score 0):

So I see some discrepancies in the package.json:

On one hand you have:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    ...
  }
```

and on the other hand you have:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.5",
    ...
  }
```

**I recommend you to consolidate around `^6.0.0` and only leave `@angular/cli` in `devDependencies`.**

Second, in case you're looking for it, the Webpack AoT compiler plugin for Angular is in `@ngtools/webpack` which you will need to install in `devDependencies`.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I just made a huge mess. I consolidate all of the @angular to ^ 6 and leave the @angular/cli in dev. that fix my problem. with that MainComponent.

Comment: new problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3k0M.png ,  can u please explain to me what its mean can't resolve all parameters, and how I got the build compiled successfully, if it is not all resolve? @Fernando